# How to configure ipage php ini to work with laravel 3?

Tags: php, laravel

I recently registered to ipage web hosting , uploaded my laravel 3 php web app , it didn't work and said that some functions are deprecated ,
I downgraded to php 5.2 it replied 
via this message :

"
**Internal Server Error**

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

"

http://codumanity.com/kalamakom-test/kalamakom/public/index.php

any help ?

Comment: Please direct your support request to ipage web hosting, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requesting support for some specific webhosting company.

Comment: Actually it's about configuring the php.ini file provied by the php version I selected on the web hosting provider .

Comment: And have you contacted technical support about the problem? What did they respond?

Comment: I didn't because I know it's not actually their problem , they give you the full access to comment/uncomment any of the dlls in the .ini file and that would finally configure your application so I believe it's me who needs to know which dlls in php has to be configured for laravel .

Comment: But I may contact them anyway , thanks ..

Comment: That makes sense. However, just telling here that PHP crashes with no further info does not get you any help. Check the laravel homepage for requirements (you install it via composer, you need a commandline-shell for that, can you SSH into your server?). And it's defenetly PHP 5.3+, it will crash with PHP 5.2. You better use the current PHP 5.4 / 5.5 stable versions.

Comment: http://three.laravel.com/docs/install

Comment: I guess yes , I can SSH into the server , I'll check laravel homepage and try to proceed . 
Thanks , and sry for not being specific I'm new here ..

Comment: this might help, too: http://wiki.laravel.io/A_Beginner's_Guide_to_Laravel_3 - just seeing for Laravel 3 you don't need composer. If you have the shell, you stil can benefit from commandline operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything , it began to work with me now :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem to run Laravel 3 is solved now, I just did the following:

1. Used PHP version 5.3 (not 5.2)
2. Set `register_long_arrays` and `register_globals` to '`off`' in `php.ini` file.

and it started to work.

Comment: where to find this php.ini?